# Umbraco 301 redirect - entire site

Tags: umbraco

I have multiple websites within one Umbraco installation.

I recently deleted a website and wish to re-direct all traffic from that website to a specific page on a different website (within Umbraco).

At the moment, I've setup a template with this macro:

```
<umbraco:Macro redirectType="[#redirectType]" redirectURL="[#redirectTo]" Alias="GenericRedirect" runat="server"></umbraco:Macro>
```

It re-directs traffic from www.domainname.com to www.otherdomainname.com/page.aspx.

The only problem is, if a user types in www.domainname.com/anypage.aspx it just gives them a 404 error.

Is there a way to re-direct ALL traffic from www.domainname.com to the page of my choice within Umbraco?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

in the config folder is an UrlRewriting.config.

with this file you can redirect a complete site to another domain:

Example (not tested)

```
<add name="domain1.com redirect"
     redirectMode="Permanent"
     redirect="Domain"
     ignoreCase="true" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
     virtualUrl="http://www.domain1.com/(.*)"
     destinationUrl="http://www.destinationdomain.nl/" />
```

(the virtualUrl is a regex)

Comment: Thanks Luuk, I did see this somewhere but wasn't sure if there was an easier way of doing things. This looks great though, thank you.

Comment: Another option could be to rightclick the domain's home-node and click 'manage hostnames' and attach the old domain to the new one. But then the trouble with the 404 errors remains the same if someone goes to the site using pagelinks.